# setting FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe) for already authnticated user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following login action method:-

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)

        {

MembershipProvider domainProvider;
domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
 {
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
}
 else
 {
ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
return View(model);
}
 return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

}
return View(model);

}
```

And the following logoff :-

```
public ActionResult LogOff2()

        {FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
```

The problem i am facing is when a user open two tabs inside the same browser, which point to the login page. and then he login from the two views (i think two authentication cookies will be created), then if he logout from one tab (invalidate one cookies), the other cookie will still be valid and user can navigate through the system . so i am thing of checking if the user is already authenticated before setting the authentication cookie as follow:-

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {

if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

}

MembershipProvider domainProvider;
domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
 {//code goes here..........
```

because having two cookies snide the same browser might be risky, because a user might lo-gin twice ,and if he lo-gout from one tab , he will assume that he have lo-gout from the whole system. while other cookie might still be valid inside the same browser . so can anyone advive ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, cookies are not tab dependant, so when a user will log out on one tab he/she will be logged out from another tab as well.

You could generate a separate cookie per tab, but this is a rather unusual scenario and your code does not represent such a scenario.

Comment: i think you did not understand my problem . As this is the current behavior, if a user open the login page twice and he type his username and password on the two views, and he click on login button , from the two views. it seems that this will generate two cookies, since if the user logout from one tab still he is login in the other. i am talking about login twice, not opening the system on two tabs.